# Mirroir between two databases on the same server

Tags: mysql, triggers, replication

On my server, I have two databases : db_first and db_second.
Theses db have exactly the same structure and I want to make a relation between them.

Exemple : db_first and db_second have a table called "account"

If I add a result into db_first.account, I want the same result in db_second.account
If I update a result into db_first.account, I want the same update in db_second.account
But if I update a result into db_second.account, I want the same update in db_first.account

So, it's a bidirectional communication.

Is it possible with MySQL ?

(please don't ask me why I have to use a solution as ugly :/)

Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are referring to is known as multi Master replication. And yes it is possible.

Comment: But how to stop infinite recursion ?
If I update db_first.account, replication procedure will update db_second.account and db_second.account will update db_first.account...

That's why it's impossible with a trigger

Comment: Have you ever tried using it? MySQL understands when a commit has come from another master server and when it has come from a client. It makes sure that only updates from clients are replicated out to slaves/masters.

Comment: Ok, thank's and do you know a good article/ book to do that ?

Comment: this might be a good hands on starting point: http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_master_master_replication
Otherwise google is your friend combined with getting your hands dirty.